# I need Show x and y axis major and minor line and points showing in Scatterplot on Core-plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am Generate Scatter Plot below code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      [self generateDataSamples];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingview=[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingview];

    graph=[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingview.hostedGraph =graph;

    CPTScatterPlot *datasourceLinePlot =[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    datasourceLinePlot.dataSource =self;

    [graph addPlot:datasourceLinePlot];

    [datasourceLinePlot release];
    [graph release];
    [hostingview release];

}
```

Output is Below:

[image]

But,I need display majorline and minorline for x and yaxis...!

like this y-0.5,1.0,1.5....! and x-0.5,1.0,1.5...!

I want to output below image:

[image]

any one help with me....!

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set major and minor tick information (sample shown below for x-axis):

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
```